# emacs cut paste

Tags: linux, user-interface, emacs, ubuntu

In emacs, when I want to cut/copy and paste (kill and yank) to or from other applications, it often does not work if I do that through keyboard shortcuts, but works if I do that by using the mouse and selecting the command under the Edit Menu. Is this a bug, or intended to be like that?

By the way, interestingly, drag-and-dropping into emacs works, but doing out of emacs does not work.

I am using **GNU emacs** 23.3 under gnome on ubuntu linux 10.04. It was like this from earlier versions of emacs and ubuntu linux.

Comment: The gui side of Emacs probably brings X-bound clipboard to the game. The usual yank/kill keys only affect Emacs' own yankring. But this is speculation.

Comment: @progo and I are making the same speculation: plain emacs cannot use keyboard shortcuts to participate in X11 cut-and-paste. (Well, maybe it depends also on your terminal; `urxvt(7)` claims to have some keyboard-based selection, but I can't figure out how to use it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably read this Emacs Wiki : http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CopyAndPaste

I think that the most important is [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CopyAndPaste#toc4) !

In a nutshell :

```
(setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed x-select-enable-clipboard is indispensable, but even on a barebones emacs, remember that you can always copy and paste by **selecting and then mouse-2 (the wheel)** and this, *all though X*. It's surprising how many people ignore this basic X trick.